# What does "API" mean in Spark's "Dataframe API"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is the meaning of "API" in Spark's *Dataframe API*?
How is it related to API?

Comment: Is an application programming interface which offers you the possibilities of dataframes as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the term **A**pplication **P**rogramming **I**nterface is mostly used for the element exposing the services of a web server, it has a more general meaning.

For frameworks as extended as *Spark*, **it names specific ways of interacting with the library** available for the user.

*Spark* features different *APIs* with different purposes, which serve as front-facing interfaces masking more complex underlying or structural code ([*Facade Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)):
Even if every *spark job* runs *RDD-based* pipelines, *Spark* offers different ways to construct a *job*:

- **Core API** (Spark Core): user manipulates directly the RDDs, it is the low level API
- **Dataset API** (Spark SQL): User manipulates high level typed objects
- **DataFrame API** (Spark SQL): User manipulates high level untyped objects
- **SQL API** (Spark SQL): User writes SQL query strings

(3 last APIs leverage a descriptive programming model and the structuration of the manipulated data to produce optimized Spark jobs)

Note: By convention, when talking about Dataset API, we talk about manipulation of `Dataset[T]` objects with T different from `Row`. The manipulation of `Dataset[Row]` objects is called DataFrame API (as `DataFrame` is a type alias for `Dataset[Row]`).